# Ascii to NetCDF conversion

Tags: python, netcdf

I'm new user of the netCDF library so I appologize for this basic question.
I'm trying to convert an ascii file with 4 columns (lon,lat,depth,velocity) to netCDF. I'm getting the following error:

Vp[:] = file[:,:,:,:]
IndexError: too many indices for array

Could you please help me to find the cause of the error? I've set the dimensions of the variables to the number of rows. Is that right?

Thanks in advance.

The file is big, you can find a sample here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qq9529vcvq8t1av/test.txt?dl=0

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import sys


file = np.loadtxt('test.txt', delimiter=' ')
# NC file setup
mydata = Dataset('Vp.nc', 'w', format='NETCDF4')
mydata.description = '3D VP velocity model'

# dimensions
mydata.createDimension('latitude', 1000)
mydata.createDimension('longitude', 1000)
mydata.createDimension('depth', 1000)

Vp = mydata.createVariable('Vp', 'f4', ('latitude', 'longitude', 'depth'), fill_value=0)

Vp[:] = file[:,:,:]
Vp.units = 'km/s'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several issues

- do not use built-in function names as variable names, like `file`
- do not put coordinate data into variable, but into separate variable
- if you add data to NetCDF variable, slice sizes must be equal
- your current error is just from asking wrong dimensions from numpy array, which is 1000,4 in your example file

Here is an example that works, but I did not extract correct variable data because I do not know the actual structure and be careful with reshaping as well.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import sys


input_file = np.loadtxt('test.txt', delimiter=' ')
# NC file setup
mydata = Dataset('Vp.nc', 'w', format='NETCDF4')
mydata.description = '3D VP velocity model'

# dimensions
mydata.createDimension('longitude', 128)
mydata.createDimension('latitude', 4)
lat = mydata.createVariable('latitude', 'f4','longitude')
lat.long_name = "latitude"
lat.units = "degrees_north"
lat.standard_name = "latitude"
lon = mydata.createVariable('longitude', 'f4','latitude')
lon.long_name = "longitude"
lon.units = "degrees_east"
lon.standard_name = "longitude"

## mydata.createVariable('depth', 1)

Vp = mydata.createVariable('Vp', 'f4', ('longitude','latitude'), fill_value=0)

Vp[:128,:4] = input_file[:512,3].reshape(128,4)
## lon[:] = ???
## lat[:] = ???
Vp.units = 'km/s'
```